# What are the key books regarding Marvel's Illuminati?

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, marvel-illuminati

Marvel's Illuminati group has grown in size since I first encountered it, and apparently has been involved in many more of the Marvel universe's major incidents. I first became aware of them in *Planet Hulk*.

Which are the key issues dealing with the formation and actions of this group, and what's the best order to read them in? I'm wondering about issue *before* the dedicated *Illuminati* series that started in 2015.

Wikipedia lists their appearances by comic line, but isn't helpful in determining how those appearances actually influenced other stories, or determining a cross-series timeline.

Comment: They had their own book at one point.